# How do I print to console in assembly?

Tags: assembly, printing, console

I would like to learn Assembly language. Just to get started, I would just print the result of, let´s say 5+5 to the console. I am using Flat Assembler in Windows 7 64bit.

I have just begin writing a code and I would like the v1 and v2 strings be printed to the console, but I don´t succeed:

```
v1 db 'Enter value 1: ', 0
val1 db 80 dup(?)
v2 db 'Enter value 2: ', 0
val2 db 80 dup(?)
```

After compiling the code I try to run it with `fasm.exe hello.ASM`, but noting is displayed. I thought I would be promted to type a value.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're declaring the data, but not doing anything with it. You can call Windows functions (e.g. OutputDebugString) or c-runtime functions (e.g. printf) to display something.

Answer (score 6):

You have to write the code to actually print the data to the console -- right now, you're just defining some blocks of data.

You'd normally print the data with something like `WriteFile` or (if you want to get fancier) `WriteConsoleOutput`. Here's a sample "Hello World" program as a starting point:

```
.386
.MODEL flat, stdcall

getstdout = -11

WriteFile PROTO NEAR32 stdcall, \
        handle:dword,           \
        buffer:ptr byte,        \
        bytes:dword,            \
        written: ptr dword,     \
        overlapped: ptr byte

GetStdHandle PROTO NEAR32, device:dword

ExitProcess PROTO NEAR32, exitcode:dword

.stack 8192

.data
message db "Hello World!"
msg_size equ $ - offset message

.data?
written  dd ?

.code
main proc   
    invoke GetStdHandle, getstdout
    invoke WriteFile,                   \
           eax,                         \
           offset message,              \
           msg_size,                    \
           offset written,              \
           0
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main endp
        end main
```

Comment: Will also require input routines as well as perhaps some decimal/binary conversions.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: Yes, but since it's obviously homework, I didn't want to just hand it everything needed...

Comment: Comment wasn't aimed at you, it was for the OP's benefit, so he wouldn't be disappointed when it didn't solve all his problems.  :-)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. First of all, this is not homework (as some kind of proof for that, maybe you can look at my previous questions to see that I have a general interest in programming languages and have asked several questions regarding different programming languages, technices etc). I have never been in contact with assembly and would just like to know about the basics. So, to print to console, I have to import libraries in some way that have that functionality, and then call those methods in that library?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. On older systems like DOS it was pretty common to just write the data to the screen buffer, but a modern system won't normally support/allow that.

Comment: How about assembly directives and instrcutions (like MOV, DB etc), I suppose they differ from architecture to architecture and from OS to OS? Any good book recomendation on this topic for att real assembly beginner like me?

Comment: @Rox: yes, they vary between systems. Most of the books I know of are specific to an individual system (e.g., manual for a particular assembler, OS, or processor). You might want to look at Randy Hyde's [The Art of Assembly Language](http://homepage.mac.com/randyhyde/webster.cs.ucr.edu/www.artofasm.com/index.html) -- though uses its own unique syntax.